# Preg_split doesn't show first character of the sentence

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$re = "/[.\!\?][\s\n\r\t][A-Z]/";
$forbiddenwords=array("on", "ja", "ning", "ega", "ehk", "või", "aga", "kuid", "ent", "vaid", "et", "kui", "kuna", "sest", "kuni", "kuigi", "ehkki", "nagu" );
$text = 'Oma eluajal ja veel 18. sajandi lõpul oli Bach tuntud vaid võrdlemisi kitsas ringkonnas, heliloojana hakati teda laialt tunnustama alles 19. sajandi esimesel poolel. Praegu peetakse teda põhiliseks heliloojaks barokiajastul ja üheks suurimaks terves muusikaajaloos. Tema loomingut on peetud saksa klassikalise muusika kõrgaja alguseks';

function splitintosentences($re, $text){
    $sentences = preg_split($re, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r ($sentences);
}

splitintosentences($re, $text);

?>
```

Everything works just fine, but when program prints out sentences, it does not show first letters of sentences. For example, if sentence is "Dog is brown", then it shows "og is brown". How to solve this?

Comment: Remove `[A-Z]` from regular expression.

Comment: It has to be there, because in other case, it splits sentences in wrong places. For example, if sentence includes phrase"18. century", it thinks 18. is end of sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need A-Z to be a lookahead:

```
 /[.!?]\s(?=[A-Z])/
```

reads: punctuation and space, *if followed by* a capital letter.